# How can I fix Algolia Autocomplete with Typesense Adapter throwing: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'headers')?

Tags: autocomplete, algolia, typesense

This is my JavaScript code:
`const SEARCH_API_KEY = '...';

```
    const {
        autocomplete, getAlgoliaResults
    } = window['@algolia/autocomplete-js'];

    const { createQuerySuggestionsPlugin } = window[
        '@algolia/autocomplete-plugin-query-suggestions'
    ];

    const { createLocalStorageRecentSearchesPlugin } = window[
        '@algolia/autocomplete-plugin-recent-searches'
    ];

    const typesenseInstantsearchAdapter = new TypesenseInstantSearchAdapter({
        server: {
            apiKey: SEARCH_API_KEY, // Be sure to use the search-only-api-key
            nodes: [
                {
                    host: '***.com',
                    port: '8108',
                    protocol: 'https'
                }
            ]
        },
        additionalSearchParameters: {
            query_by: 'query'
        },
        transporter: {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
        }
    });

    const searchClient = typesenseInstantsearchAdapter.searchClient;

    const querySuggestionsPlugin = createQuerySuggestionsPlugin({
        searchClient,
        indexName: 'agro_products_query_suggestions',
    });

    autocomplete({
        container: '#autocomplete',
        plugins: [querySuggestionsPlugin],
    });`
```

It was working just fine without any issue and all of a sudden it's throwing following error since yesterday:

`Autocomplete-js:8 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'headers') at autocomplete-js:8:83332 at autocomplete-js:8:83454 at autocomplete-js:8:83864 at n (autocomplete-js:8:82737) at autocomplete-js:8:30965 at Array.map (<anonymous>) at Be (autocomplete-js:8:30875)`

any help will be much appreciated

I tried several solutions such as providing a custom transporter, but, no luck!